# Async in ajax does not work anymore under Chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I am using the jquery 1.9 for months and I do a `$.ajax` with jQuery when the user click on a link.

Actually, when the user clicks on that link, a ajax query is performed while the next page is beeing loaded (long loading). This used to work perfectly with `async: false` under Chrome and IE 9.

But I have updated Chrome to the latest version two weeks ago and this does not work anymore (ajax is not loaded but next page appears). But it stil works under IE.

EDIT here is my code for $.ajax:

```
function doOnClick(id) {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'http://...",
        async: false,
        data: { id : id }
    }).success(function(data) {
        //do some stuff
}).fail(function(){ 
        //do some stuff 
    });
}
```

and my link:

```
<a href="http://..." onclick="doOnClick(1);">link</a>
```

I have no error in my JS console.

Comment: Adding code is a good practice :)

Comment: In 99.99% of case, `async: false` shouldn't be used. Now provide relevant code you are using. BTW, check your console, any error? Just wondering, are you trying to override onbeforeunload event behaviour? If ya, chrome no more support it. And in this case, this is the only AFAIK case where synchronous ajax request was accurate. Now a simple workaround is of course possible

Comment: Chrome stopped supporting `async: false`? Time to celebrate, I guess :-D

Comment: Can't confirm. `async.false` still works in my version of Chrome.

Comment: I edited my post to provide code.

Comment: @Florent06 still not enough context. How/when do you call this ajax request?

Comment: What's the URL? What's `param`? What is "some stuff"? Have you set anything through `$.ajaxSetup`? Your code sample doesn't really show anything, and it doesn't reproduce issue. Please provide a self-contained code (no references to variables declared outside) that demonstrates the issue (make sure to actually run it). Ideally, provide a http://jsfiddle.net link, too.

Comment: OK... you've provided a success handler. Why do you still want to use `async:false`?

Comment: @JanDvorak async false could be used to block anchor redirection while request is still processing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use async request, set option context:

```
$('.someLinks').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: url,
        data: param,
        context: this
    }).success(function (data) {
        //do some stuff
    }).fail(function () {
        //do some stuff 
    }).always(function () {
        this.click(); // call native click method // NOTE: don't use here: $(this).click();
    });
});
```

Comment: "call native click method" is almost always undesired as it results in navigation, which we probably don't want just after performing an AJAX call.

Comment: @JanDvorak following question, seems the behaviour OP is expecting

Comment: I dont want my page to be loaded AFTER my ajax query is responsed but I want my ajax query to be performed WHILE my page is being loaded.

Comment: @Florent06 that's impossible. First your old page gets unloaded, after which point it can no longer do anything (AJAX included), then the new one starts loading. That is, unless you do page loading through AJAX (which needs extra effort to make work properly with browser history)

Comment: @Florent06 then that's not possible. If it works on some browser, there is no cross browser 'rule' to handle something like that. And anyway, the behaviour you are looking for doesn't make much sense and doesn't fit with behaviour of code you are currently using